# UITableViewCell and allocation problems

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode-instruments

I want to use a custom reusable UITableViewCell with my UItableview, it works but, testing with instruments - allocation, I see that memory is not released when I get out of my UIViewController and re-enter several times.

here are the three methods that i've tried,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // method #1
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"customClassicCell";
    customClassicCell *cell = (customClassicCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customClassicCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[customClassicCell class]])
            {
                cell = (customClassicCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

or

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier44 = @"custom44";
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.tbv registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"customClassicCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier44];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // method #2
    customClassicCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier44];

    return cell;
}
```

or

```
// method3
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier44];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier44] ;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

instrument shows this (every times I get out and get in my UIviewcontroller), it's the same problem with the 3 methods, memory is not correctly released.
[image: instruments-allocation]

[image: instruments-allocation-2]

I use xcode 5.0 target 5.1

I do not use ARC neither storyboards. Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: if you step out and re-enter your view controller several times, do you see memory going up dramatically each time you recreate your table view?  I bet you ***do not***.  Once the cell has been created, it sticks around in memory until it's explicitly released (since you're not using ARC); but then again, you're re-using those cells (and their memory) each time you go into your table view.

Comment: you can see on the graph, the only thing i'm doing is getting in then getting out, then I click on the button "mark generation".
5 cells are shown in the tablewview, that's only an example. do you see persistent column ?

Comment: Is your view controller being deallocated when you exit the view?  It sounds like it's not which means something is strongly retaining it when it shouldn't be.  Your `dealloc` method in that view controller should be called and used to unload all of those allocations

Comment: thanks iWasRobbed, i have not looked for the problem at the right place, it was a dealloc problem.